# Allow user selection to determine the stock selection in web.DataReader

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I'm looking to create a program that will take a user selected stock and 
return information using the `web.DataReader` function in Pandas. Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web   # Package and modules for importing data; this code may change depending on pandas version
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

apple = web.DataReader(input(""), "yahoo", start, end)

type(apple)
apple.head()
```

Results with

> input("") in web.DataReader statement
>
> OSError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=appl&a=0&b=1&c=2016&d=11&e=8&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv'

Comment: Try to run the `input` command before, i.e. outside of the function?

Comment: Can you show us what you've typed in the `input("")`?

Comment: @IanS, good idea, I got it working!

Comment: This doesn't help with your immediate problem but you really need to stop using the `pandas.io.data` module. They have ported everything over into an entirely new package called pandas_datareader. You need to pip install that one. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure you typed `appl` for the ticker, when apple's ticker is actually `AAPL`. Try running `web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)` instead.

Comment: @JulienMarrec, nothing like good old user error. Joys of 5 am programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should really do it now that the data readers have been moved into their own package. You also need to provide a valid ticker, in case of apple it's `AAPL` and not `appl`

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

apple = data.DataReader(input("Please Input the name of the Ticker:\n"), "yahoo", start, end)

type(apple)
apple.head()

Please Input the name of the Ticker:
AAPL

    Open    High    Low     Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
2016-01-04  102.610001  105.370003  102.000000  105.349998  67649400    103.057063
2016-01-05  105.750000  105.849998  102.410004  102.709999  55791000    100.474523
2016-01-06  100.559998  102.370003  99.870003   100.699997  68457400    98.508268
2016-01-07  98.680000   100.129997  96.430000   96.449997   81094400    94.350769
2016-01-08  98.550003   99.110001   96.760002   96.959999   70798000    94.849671
```